# Is there a way to use PHPmailer with default from as sendmail_from php.ini directive?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I would like to use PHPmailer with my php.ini sendmail_from directive, but I didn't find a way to do this : PHPmailer always takes his own default configuration (root@localhost). 
Is there a way to get the value specified in PHP.ini then retrieve it in PHPmailer as the default from value ? Which one ?
Thanks for your answers !

Comment: you cloud use ini_get to get the setting then set it manually the problem arise that using sendmail php logs into it using `root@localhost` so sendmail will auto set the send from header in the email to the logged in user i think this bug has been reported but i can't find it now... this also changes depending on how php exec is handled if i remember correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Martin Barker comment, here's what I did :

I created a new class which inherits from PHPmailer, then in the __construct function I do this :

```
$this->From = ini_get('sendmail_from');
$this->FromName = ini_get('sendmail_from');
```

And it works. There is probably a better way to do this, but it will do the trick for the moment.