# PHPMailer not sending Emails on One Host but sends on another Host

Tags: php, phpmailer

PHPMailer sends emails on one host but doesn't send on another host using exactly the same code.

I contacted the host and they sent me the following screenshot
[image]

The server protects from email, so they indicated that to send the emails from a different host or with any host, I have to use `ini_set( 'sendmail_from', 'email@example.com' );`. Well, that solution works fine for the normal PHP mail function, `mail()` but not for the PHPMailer.

Would someone help me figure out how to solve this issue on PHPMailer?

The following is my code, which has been tested on another hosting and works fine only on the current server where no email gets sent despite using `ini_set()`

```
require_once('email-sending/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php');
require_once('email-sending/PHPMailer/Exception.php');

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; 

/*!
 * 
 * 
 * This class handles the sending and processing of emails
 * 
 * */

class Email{

    const BASE_URL      = 'http://cryptodegen.co.uk'; // please enter domain name of your website without the trailing slash, e.g https://example.com

    const SHORT_DOMAIN  = 'cryptodegen.co.uk'; // Enter short domain without https e.g example.com

    const SYSTEM_NAME   = 'Crypto Degen '; // Website Name

    const LOGO_URL      = self::BASE_URL . '/email-sending/logo/logo-black1.png'; // your website logo, if blank emails will be sent without logo

    const FOOTER_TEXT   = 'Crypto Degen, San Francisco CA 94102, This text is editable'; // footer text

    const EMAIL_SENDER  = 'noreply@cryptodegen.co.uk'; //

    const REPLY_TO      = 'info@cryptodegen.co.uk'; // senders will reply to



    /*!
     * 
     * $to = recepient, $subject = Email Subject, $message = HTML MESSAGE
     * 
     * $ttachements should be array of files url
     * 
     * 
     * $attachemnet is optional, you can jsut say:
     * Email::send( 'catekhui@gmail.com', 'Urgent subject', Hello html email message' );
     * 
     * 
     * */
    static function send( $to, $subject, $message, $attachments = array() ){
        try {
            ini_set( "sendmail_from", self::EMAIL_SENDER );
            $email = new PHPMailer( true );
            $email->SetFrom( self::EMAIL_SENDER, self::SHORT_DOMAIN );
            $email->Subject   = $subject;
            $email->Body      = get_email_template( $message );
            $email->AddAddress( $to );
            $email->isHTML(true);
            $email->addReplyTo( self::REPLY_TO, '' );

            foreach ($attachments as $key => $value) {
                // code...
                $email->AddAttachment( $value , basename( $value ) );
            }

            $email->Send();

            return true;
        } catch( Exception $e ){
            ?> 
                <script>
                     window.onload = function() {
                        alert("<?php echo $e; ?>");
                   }
                </script>
            <?php
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: this might solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435395/is-there-a-way-to-use-phpmailer-with-default-from-as-sendmail-from-php-ini-direc

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the envelope sender, which is separate from the from address. Try this:

```
$mail->Sender = self::EMAIL_SENDER;
```